# 1-byte-long ByteBuffer allocate or allocateDirect

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I'm writing a library for reading/writing bits from/to Streams/Channels.

When working with Channels I use 1-byte-long ByteBuffer.

Here comes how to read/write with those ByteBuffer.

```java
//@Override // commented for pre 5
public int readUnsignedByte() throws IOException {

    buffer.clear(); // ------------------------------------------- clear

    for (int read = -1;;) {
        read = input.read(buffer); // ----------------------------- read
        if (read == -1) {
            throw new EOFException("eof");
        }
        if (read == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    buffer.flip(); // --------------------------------------------- flip

    return (buffer.get() & 0xFF); // ------------------------------- get
}


//@Override // commented for pre 5
public void writeUnsignedByte(final int value) throws IOException {

    buffer.put((byte) value); // ----------------------------------- put

    buffer.flip(); // --------------------------------------------- flip

    while (output.write(buffer) != 1); // ------------------------ write

    buffer.clear(); // ------------------------------------------- clear
}
```

In this case, does `allocateDirect(1)` is always better than `allocate(1)`?

Comment: probably, but I doubt you will notice much difference.

Comment: If you're using blocking mode the loops around `read()` and `write()` are redundant, and if you're using non-blocking mode they are a serious waste of your CPU: you should be integrating with a `Selector` and allowing a zero length read or write to occur. I also question the utility of a 1 byte buffer: the performance will be truly appalling. I would reconsider the design.